# Is there a book or website or software with core English words that allow you to understand every English word?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a book or website or software with core English words that allow you to understand every English word?

These core words can give us the meaning of every English word in the entire English literature.

Let us say I want to write a book in English and I don't want to use words that can be described with core words then where do I find the complete list of core words?

What I am saying is, it will be a book written using core words only, this book does not need other words, words that have a meaning defined using core words. So no words that can be defined with basic or core words are needed in this book. The text size will increase but it will be a book written using basic or core English words, words that don't miss anything, words that can define every English word that ever existed and every word that will ever be added on time to time basis to ever growing English language. Let us say few new words need words that are not basic and I don't want those words. For example let us say there is a new English word that needs a name of a place in its definition and this name of a place is not a basic or core word, then I don't need such words.

All I want is all the basic or core English words that can describe anything or everything in the Entire Universe. For example let us say there is a word in English that can be defined using basic or core English words then I don't want that word if that word can't be considered as a core word too.

Kindly point me towards such a book or website or software that is already available on the internet.

Thanks.

Comment: " … *words that can define every English word that ever existed and every word that will ever be added on time to time basis to ever growing English language.*" Very Orwellian, look up **newspeak**.

Comment: Ask yourself if the same could be done in your native language or dialect. Defining every single word with the same simplified and limited corpus

Comment: @Anton That's so true, and if you can't do it for mathematics which is really tightly defined you certainly can't do it for a natural language which is much less tightly defined to start with and keeps evolving all the time anyway.

Comment: There is Ogden's "Basic English".  http://ogden.basic-english.org

Comment: [**Green Eggs and Ham**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Eggs_and_Ham)

Comment: Everything in the entire universe? There are unknown unknowns (although this is unprovable).

Comment: Excellent Dr. Seuss reference, @HotLicks.Vocabulary of exactly 50 words. Can't think of too much literature that uses "Sam-I-am" as a core word, though.

Comment: @rajah9 Does it have 'sausage'?

Comment: Heh heh, Drawing only from Dr. Seuss's 50 words (c.f., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Eggs_and_Ham): "Sam will not eat that. Sam will not try it. Not in a box. Not in a car. Let me be, @EdwinAshworth"

Comment: I went to https://xkcd.com/simplewriter/ to try to explain *sausage* bereft of adjectives like *spicy, cooked* or nouns like *tube, meat, flesh*. simplewriter doesn't accept any of these words ("You used some less simple words: cooked"). The best sentence I could come up with was *I like to eat hot dog,* but unfortunately that makes the *hot dog* not a sausage, but rather a Dacshund with a fever.

Comment: A foreign language is not a math problem to be solved, or even addressed with mathematical thinking. I'm afraid that there are no secret formulas that will save you the effort of having to learn the same way we all learn.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/txt/al.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the tightly-defined world of mathematics, there are fundamental, *core* rules, which correspond to your *core* words in English. These core rules are called *axioms*.

It seems that you are looking for the axiomatic words in English. You can find these words in a dictionary, but they don't have good definitions. They have weasel words that describe things about the word.

Consider the definition of the most axiomatic, core word in English: *the*.

> the, definite article
>
> Definition of the (Entry 1 of 4)
> 1a—used as a function word to indicate that a following noun or noun equivalent is definite or has been previously specified by context or by circumstance
> *put the cat out*
>
> b—used as a function word to indicate that a following noun or noun equivalent is a unique or a particular member of its class
> *the President*,
> *the Lord*
>
> c—used as a function word before nouns that designate natural phenomena or points of the compass
> *the night is cold*
>
> (and on it goes for another 3-1/2 definitions).

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the))

Did you see the definition of *the*? Neither did I. I see how the word is used, not what it means.

So a dictionary will contain the axiomatic words, but you can only detect the base words by their lack of definition. (This is a paradox with a hat-tip to @Anton and the reference to the Gödel's incompleteness theorem.)

**An attempt was made**

The author of the comic, xkcd, (a.k.a Randall Munroe), has written a book called [Thing Explainer: Complicated Stuff in Simple Words](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0544668251). He uses a core, axiomatic vocabulary of one thousand words to explain many everyday concepts and devices. For example, he has a page devoted to the

> *food-heating radio boxes* (microwaves)

His pictures are worth *ten hundred* words, but you might be most interested in the *ten hundred* words in the back.

Alas, these thousand words only cover appliances and scientific concepts (although the orders-of-magnitude and astronomy pages are worth the price of the book).

While *Thing Explainer* deals with science and engineering, I know of no books that describe the axiomatic words of literature.

Comment: -1. Answering a question that will (rightly) be closed undermines the integrity of our site. As an experienced user, you should understand this.

Comment: To recognise that there are those who will inappropriately close a question is not to say that it should be closed. On the contrary, an answer may also demonstrate that it should not be closed

Comment: Thank you for explaining the downvote. While I admit that the question may have been borderline (in that it asked for a reference), it was not my intent to impugn the integrity of EL&U.  I hasten to point out: The question had no close votes when I answered it.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a book or website or software with core English words that allow you to understand every English word?

No, and there never will be. In the first place, to understand such a book, you would have to understand every word. It would be of little use and indexing it would be a nightmare.

English words are either single words, e.g.

(i) “cat” from the Old English “catte” but which now has several meanings, or

(ii)    compound words that start with “cat” as a prefix, e.g. “catalogue” “catatonic” cata = Greek κατα-, κατ-, καθ-, a preposition used to form compounds in various senses.

(iii)   Catnip in which “cat” is redundant - Origin: A borrowing from Latin. Etymon: Latin nepeta – the cat herb.

(iv) Two words that appear to be the same may have quite distinct origins.

The difficulty is clear – prefixes (and suffixes) were originally a single word but have evolved in different ways such that they now can imply quite distinct ideas, and compound words take on a meaning of their own.

Comment: -1. I don't understand why three highly experienced users would each post an answer to an obviously off-topic question. It's the responsibility of experienced users to VTC such a question, not to chase votes before the EL&U community removes the question from circulation.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica *I don't understand* You perhaps never will understand a desire to be helpful towards a genuine poster at the cost of rules. The price is low and any damage, slight.

Answer (score -2):

The question will probably be closed.

However, you raise fundamental and very interesting issues that relate, for example, to the function, purpose and structure of dictionaries. I therefore answer it.

In mathematics, Godel’s theorem deals with the impossibility of establishing all truths from a limited set of axioms.

David Hilbert proposed to ground all existing theories to a finite, complete set of axioms, and provide a proof that these axioms were consistent. Hilbert proposed that the consistency of more complicated systems, such as real analysis, could be proven in terms of simpler systems.

Godel proved Hilbert’s proposal to be unattainable.

> Gödel's incompleteness theorems, published in 1931, showed that Hilbert's program was unattainable for key areas of mathematics. In his first theorem, Gödel showed that any consistent system with a computable set of axioms which is capable of expressing arithmetic can never be complete: it is possible to construct a statement that can be shown to be true, but that cannot be derived from the formal rules of the system. In his second theorem, he showed that such a system could not prove its own consistency, so it certainly cannot be used to prove the consistency of anything stronger with certainty. This refuted Hilbert's assumption that a finitistic system could be used to prove the consistency of itself, and therefore anything else
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_program)

Your notion involves establishing all meanings from a limited set of words. It parallels Hilbert’s proposal.

In consequence, your notion is likely to be both formally and practically unattainable, which is why you have found no such site or reference: none will ever be found.

Comment: What I am saying is, if you look at the meaning of a word in the dictionary you will find that the meaning of the word is described by core words, that is what I am saying.

Comment: And what Godel proved is that it is impossible in the parallel case of core mathematical axioms defining some greater truths. As a crude example, a set of core words cannot describe the set of words defined as being the set of all those words not definable by core words

Comment: -1. Answering a question that you expect will (rightly) be closed undermines the integrity of our site. As an experienced user, you should understand this.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica To recognise that there are those who will inappropriately close a question is not to say that it should be closed. On the contrary, an answer may also demonstrate that it should not be closed.